# Unable to use button on last page of the viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I made a viewpager which comprises of a button which is used to display the next slide. When the viewpager displays the last page, the button then redirects it to another activity. However, the button only works if I use it to slide between pages as well. It doesn't work if I swipe till the last page and then click on the button.

[image]

Here is the viewpager code

```
public class IntroClas extends AppCompatActivity {

private ViewPager screenPager;
IntroViewPagerAdapter introViewPagerAdapter ;
TabLayout tabIndicator;
ImageView btnNext;
int position = 0 ;
Button btnGetStarted;
Animation btnAnim ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // make the activity on full screen

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    // when this activity is about to be launch we need to check if its openened before or not

    if (restorePrefData()) {

        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class );
        startActivity(mainActivity);
        finish();


    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro_clas);

    // hide the action bar


    // ini views
    btnNext = findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    tabIndicator = findViewById(R.id.tab_indicator);
    btnAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.button_animation);

    // fill list screen

    final List<ScreenItem> mList = new ArrayList<>();
    mList.add(new ScreenItem("Welcome to Kaze","Thanks for downloading Kazé!\n" +
            "We're glad you're here.\n",R.drawable.ic_onboard1));

    mList.add(new ScreenItem("","Be together whenever, with our free all-in-one communication app, complete with unlimited text service.",R.drawable.ic_onboard2));

    mList.add(new ScreenItem("","Kazé uses your phone's Internet connection (4G/3G/2G/EDGE or Wi-Fi, as available) to let you message friends and family, so you don't have to pay for every message.",R.drawable.ic_onboard3));

    mList.add(new ScreenItem("","Keep in touch with you loved ones anywhere in the world.",R.drawable.ic_onboard4));


    // setup viewpager
    screenPager =findViewById(R.id.screen_viewpager);
    introViewPagerAdapter = new IntroViewPagerAdapter(this,mList);
    screenPager.setAdapter(introViewPagerAdapter);

    // setup tablayout with viewpager

    tabIndicator.setupWithViewPager(screenPager);

    // next button click Listner

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            position = screenPager.getCurrentItem();
            if (position < mList.size()) {

                position++;
                screenPager.setCurrentItem(position);


            }

            if (position == mList.size()-1) { // when we reach to the last screen

                btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainActivity);
                        // also we need to save a boolean value to storage so next time when the user run the app
                        // we could know that he is already checked the intro screen activity
                        // i'm going to use shared preferences to that process
                        savePrefsData();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

}

private boolean restorePrefData() {

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean isIntroActivityOpnendBefore = pref.getBoolean("isIntroOpnend",false);
    return  isIntroActivityOpnendBefore;

}

private void savePrefsData() {

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isIntroOpnend",true);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Below is the XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".IntroClas">

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/screen_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_indicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/indicator_selector"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btn_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.947"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tab_indicator"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_next_btn" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the layout screen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="406dp" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intro_description"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sfpro_light"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intro_img"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.303" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/intro_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intro_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/kelanamorris"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/intro_img"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.729"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`startActivity` strictly instead of setting (again) listener

```
position = screenPager.getCurrentItem();
if (position < mList.size() - 1) {
    position++;
    screenPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
else { // when we reach to the last screen
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
    // also we need to save a boolean value to storage so next time when the user run the app
    // we could know that he is already checked the intro screen activity
    // i'm going to use shared preferences to that process
    savePrefsData();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Not working. I want the intent only to be opened when I click on the button.

Comment: if `setCurrentItem` is working (switching pages) then in `else` you have `startActivity` with `Intent mainActivity` (which in fact points on `LoginActivity.class`). code posted in my answer is so simple that I don't see a possibility for not-working...

Comment: if you need to start new `Activity` always, without switching pages then just remove `if` statement and leave only part of code placed in `else`